# Give point to author on post view Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

How can I check if an authenticated user already viewed a post on the first occasion? I am trying to credit the author's points when they receive views on their post, but the view must be unique. If the user viewing the post should view the same post again, the author should be given no point. How can I do this?

```
public function mount(Post $post)
{
    $this->post = $post;

    views($post)->cooldown(24)->record();

    if (views($post)->count() > 1) {
        $user = auth()->user();
        $point = Point::find(1);
        
        // or via HasPoint trait method
        $user->achievePoint($point);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This question is similar to another one posted here long ago. This is a part of the best answer give by user Edelans:

In database:
You hold a record for each view. Relating that record to a user in some way e.g. MemberID, IP Address; something that should be unique to the user. IP is not ideal but good enough if you are not requiring users to login.

So you would have for example a table with the following columns,

- ArticleID (Foreign Key)
- UserID (Foreign Key)
- Date

The date will be useful for a couple of reasons,

- Reporting. You can build much better statistics once you know when
  each view was recorded.
- View Timeouts. For example, you may only want to store one view per
  user per hour. With the date column held you can do this.

Entire post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/943967/how-view-count-is-best-implemented).